# I am unable to compile the audience targeting while creating a new rule by using powershell script and xml?

Tags: powershell, xml, audience-targeting

I am unable to Compile the audience targeting while creating a new rule by using PowerShell scripts and XML file. I selected SPS-location property.  while complying It throws an error message

```
An error occurred while attempting to update audience membership. Error in rule: SPS-Location
```

like these,But If I created it manually means it's working, Please suggest me some ideas to solve this issues.

Thanks !